# How can I fix an error I am getting with jasmine init

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-headless-webkit

I have an issue with using jasmine init.

When I hit enter I get the following output:

```
    $ jasmine init
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': cannot load such file -- jasmine-core (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jasmine-2.3.1/lib/jasmine/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jasmine-2.3.1/lib/jasmine.rb:25:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jasmine-2.3.1/lib/jasmine.rb:24:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jasmine-2.3.1/lib/jasmine.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jasmine-2.3.1/bin/jasmine:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jasmine:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jasmine:23:in `<main>'
```

I was setting things up to use jasmine-headless-webkit and not being a pro user was following vague instructions and am not sure where things went wrong.

Initially I had jasmine init working but then I started getting the above.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to rollback to a previous state, pre my attempts to install anything to do with jasmine, and then started over.

It seems to be working now.